# Sinch, message shouldSendPushNotification not being called

Tags: sinch

I'm trying to implement the push functionality in Sinch.

I've set up my since client as such:

```
[_client setSupportMessaging:YES];
[_client setSupportPushNotifications:YES];

_client.delegate = self;

[_client start];
[_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];
```

Then on

```
- (void)clientDidStart:(id<SINClient>)client {
    client.messageClient.delegate = self;
}
```

And in AppDelegate.h

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // get previously initiated Sinch client
    id<SINClient> client = [SinchClient sharedClient].client;
    [client registerPushNotificationData:deviceToken];
}
```

The other delegate methods work fine (messageSent, messageDelivered, etc), however, I can't seem to invoke

```
(void)message:(id<SINMessage>)message shouldSendPushNotifications:(NSArray *)pushPairs
```

for testing, I've setup two phones each running a SinchClient, and force quit the app on the one of the phones (assuming that should trigger the offline state) - still no dice though. I'm watching a breakpoint, but the delegate doesn't seem to be firing.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
 Charlie

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that both phones have registered push data (won't work on a simulator for example). Otherwise, putting one of these devices in flight mode and try to send a message to that device should suffice to get the `shouldSendPushNotification` callback (make sure you are signed in as different user on the two devices).
 If you don't receive the `messageSent` callback you won't receive the `shouldSendPushNotification` callback. Likewise, if you receive the `messageDelivered` event, you won't get the `shouldSendPushNotification`.