# Sinch delegate method "shouldSendPushNotification" not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, sinch

I'm playing with Sinch and have some problems with Push notifications.

- Firstly I can use Sinch to send and receive messages (two devices
  with two different Sinch IDs). So that means the Sinch Client is
  correctly configured.
- Secondly I can confirm the push notification are correctly set on
  both of the devices, because I can send push notifications to them on
  Parse.com. They all have valid push notification tokens.

Then in my app, I found that the Sinch delegate method: `shouldSendPushNotification` is not called when the receiver side is not "online".

I did a search on SO and found there's a similar question ([Sinch, message shouldSendPushNotification not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962771/sinch-message-shouldsendpushnotification-not-being-called)) which suggested to check the `messageSent` call back.

Therefore I tried the following in the receiver side:

- put the app into background by pressing home
- force quit the app (double click home, remove the app from background)
- enable flight mode

After that when a message sent, I can see:

`- (void)messageSent:(id<SINMessage>)message recipientId:(NSString *)recipientId`

is being invoked in the sender's side and the `recipientId` is the same as the destination device's. But the `shouldSendPushNotification` method is never being called as stated in Sinch's documentation.

Since this `shouldSendPushNotification` method is not invoked, there will not be any push notifications being sent out to the destination device.

I've been working on this problem for several days, and very keen to know the solution, any help is appreciated.

**Test environment**

two devices in iOS 8 beta 4 and one in iOS 7.1.2

build using XCode 6 beta 4

### Code:

Setting up the Sinch messaging service in `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    // setup Parse

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxx"
                  clientKey:@"xxxxx"];
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        // use registerUserNotificationSettings
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories: UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // use registerForRemoteNotifications
        // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
    #else
    // use registerForRemoteNotifications
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    #endif

    // app response from the notifications while in background
    NSDictionary* remotePush = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remotePush) {
        // Extract the Sinch-specific payload from the Apple Remote Push Notification
        NSString* payload = [remotePush objectForKey:@"SIN"];
        // Get previously initiated Sinch client
        id<SINNotificationResult> result = [_client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:payload];
        if (result.isMessage) {
            // Present alert notifying
            NSString *messageId = [[result messageResult] messageId];
            NSLog(@"Received messageid: %@", messageId);
        } else if (!result.isValid) {
            // Handle error
        }
        NSLog(@"Received Payload: %@", payload);
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)initSinchClientWithUserId:(NSString *)userId {
    if (!_client) {
        _client = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:@"xxxx"
                                applicationSecret:@"xxxx"
                                  environmentHost:@"sandbox.sinch.com"
                                           userId:userId];

        _client.delegate = self;

        [_client setSupportMessaging:YES];
        [_client setSupportPushNotifications:YES];
        [_client setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:NO];
        [_client start];
        [_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];
    }
}
```

And this line is called as expected when the app starts

```
- (void)clientDidStart:(id<SINClient>)client {
    NSLog(@"Sinch client started successfully (version: %@)", [Sinch version]);
}
```

Inside the app's MessageSendingViewController

```
- (id<SINClient>)client {
    return [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
...
[self.client messageClient].delegate = self;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with some help from the Sinch.

First make sure that `client` is not nil (0x0) when the delegate method `registerPushNotificationData:deviceToken` is being called.

In my case, I need to manually register notification settings again after starting the Sinch client.

Once the client is started and notification settings are registered, the `shouldSendPushNotification` method should be called without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Are you registering "push data" (e.g. your APN token) via the method `-[SINClient registerPushNotificationData:]`?

Try something like:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [_client registerPushNotificationData:deviceToken];
}
```

(There is also more details here on http://www.sinch.com/docs/ios/user-guide/#pushnotifications)

Comment: hi, thx for the help. I can confirm I had that line in my code. As I can receive the Push notifications from other service (like Parse.com), the push notifications should work properly.